# Vmware ESX 5.1- Consolidate a VM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esx, consolidation

One of my virtual machines needs consolidation. If I start Consolidation, will my vm be unaivalable, or it will continue to work and do the consolidation in the background?

thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run VM consolidation without a major impact to your VM.

It's not meant to take the VM offline.